# jQuery file upload plugin uploads the first image again on uploading the second one

Tags: jquery, jquery-file-upload

I'm using the basic version of jQuery file upload plugin -> https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin

I tried to trigger file uploads on clicking of a submit button instead of the default submission on selecting files. For this, I set the autoUpload option to false (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#autoupload), and setup the add callback (https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Options#add).

The first time uploading a file, everything goes perfect and file uploads on clicking the submit button. However, the second time I upload, the click event handler on submit fires twice and uploads the previous file along with uploading the current one.

The fileupload code:

```
$('#create-image').fileupload({
  dataType: 'json',
  singleFileUploads: false,
  autoUpload: false,
  add: function(e, data) {
    $(".button.img-submit").click(function() {
      console.log(data);
      data.submit();
    });
  },
```

Comment: where do you define "data"?

Comment: @Matt.S nowhere. data holds the information regarding the request queue that gets submitted. It has fields such as fileInput and files.

Answer (score 0):

Issue resolved. 
The click event handler was binding everytime the add callback was fired. 
So, the first time an image is uploaded, handler is bound to the button for that file. The second time, the handler is bound again, now for the second file. Because of which, both files are submitted on clicking the button the second time around.
Adding an unbind to the button before binding a click event handler solved that problem.
Modified code:

```
$('#create-image').fileupload({
  dataType: 'json',
  singleFileUploads: false,
  autoUpload: false,
  add: function(e, data) {
    $(".button.img-submit").unbind().click(function() {
      data.submit();
    });
  },
```